# Adding multiple series to navigator that are independent of what's displayed in the main chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to make a highstock chart where the navigator shows summarized data of whats in the main chart. For example, the main chart area will be showing multiple series of a weeks worth of time series data in 5-minute increments while the navigator will have show the whole time series (potentially years long) span in 4 hour increments for each line in the main chart. How should I go about adding these custom series to the navigator?

Comment: You can add a custom series in a navigator via [navigator.series](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/navigator.series). See example http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/navigator/series-data/

Comment: @morganfree Sorry, I should have worded my original question better. I'm specifically looking for a way to have multiple custom series in the navigator. In my current project I have 1 custom series in the navigator working well, but i have been struggling to get multiple custom series working.

Comment: You can  combine series.showInNavigator with series.visible properties - http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.area.showInNavigator. Define all your series in the series object - series for the navigator with showInNavigator = true, visible = false, series for the main area exactly the opposite http://jsfiddle.net/70dswtt5/